# coding guidelines - consistent variable naming

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

I am currently writing a coding style guideline for junior devlopers, and I am curious if anyone uses list of common variable names (for basic concepts), to limit confusion in codebase?

For example:

- for email address: **email** (and not: *mail*, *e-mail*, *address*, *mail_address* ...)
- for database name: **dbname** (and not: *db*, *dbase*, *base*, *database*, *database_name*, *dbn* ...)
- for file name with full qualified path: **filepath** (and not: *file*, *path*, *file_name*, *pathtofile* ...)
- for relative file name (without path) : **filename** (and not: *file*, *name*, *f*, ...)
- for configuration object : **config** (and not: *configuration*, *conf*, *vars*, ...)

Do you use similiar conventions?

**Edit**:

To be precise: it is not about **formatting** convention (*camelCaps* or *names_with_underscores*) which tends to be language and project dependant, but about **naming** convention (*mail*, *email* or *courriel*), something which is common for all the languages (like convention of using *i*, *j*, *k* for iteration counters)

Comment: En email address is not an email. An email has a from address, and one or more recipient addresses.

Comment: depends of language ;). But i think that shows precisely the purpose of such convention.

Comment: So, how did it go? Could you link us to your finished coding style guideline?

Comment: when i finish, I will share it :) But that will not occur before the Christmas (that is clearly not my top priority project)

Answer (score 3):

Pick a consistent convention and stick to it.

Your suggested convention is not consistent. **email** is using [the English word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email), so instead of dbname you should use **database_name**. Also, **file_path**, **file_name**, **configuration**.

In short, I suggest full English words, separated by '_'. This is consistent and is the convention used in Eiffel. Other systems may be consistent, too. But not a mix of everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is micro management of the worst kind. Just say "Try to use clear nonambiguous variable names." Tell them to prefer longer names and just use code completion to save typing.

Use pair programming and code review if you need to teach juniors to write code that makes sense to other people.

You need to trust them to do the right thing and correct them when they don't.

And don't make up your own conventions, it's very likely the language you're using already has conventions in its culture, like for example camelCaseForVariableNames in Java. Just follow those.

Comment: it will not work, as we have many developers (me included) for which english is not a primary language...

Comment: @ts: I don't understand, what won't work and why?

Comment: asking developers to use good names without guiding them. They are from different countries, with different levels of english language. Apart of using many synonims of the same term in english, it happens quite often that they start to use their native language to name vars, some methods or make comments ("it is not part of API, so no one cares" attitude).  All we want here is to make code maintenance easier.  And making guideline is imho opposite to mistrust. I think that before making corrections it is good to express clearly what is expected,

Comment: So tell them to write code in english, and so what if they use synonyms as long as they're clear and nonambiguous.

Comment: Also, to add. Sometimes i say half jokingly that 90% of programming is just choosing good names for things. If someone told me what names i could use it would be like they were trying to do my job for me, and would hamper my programming ability.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström : well, in my world 90% of programming  is a maintenance ;) Concerning choosing names - you can't choose names of native functions, api methods and variables, system libraries and so on... I don't see any problem with the standards.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: they used plenty of synonyms, and they **were** *unclear* and *ambiguous*. That's the problem

Comment: @ts: So were they unclear and ambiguous *because* they were synonyms?

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: in one project i found:  name, lastname, family_name, familyname, surname, nom and nom_famille, all referring to the same piece of data in different places. Also currency_rate,  exchange_rate and currency, all decribing currency rate, as opposed to class devise, representing currency. And so on, and so on. Imagine maintenance of that mess?

Comment: First, those names are not especially unclear or ambiguous, except maybe "nom". Maybe tell them to try to use the same names as are already used elsewhere in the project?

Comment: Also, depending on the language in use you might already have an obvious name. For example, in Java i might have a `Person` object with a `getLastName()` method, in which case the obvious name of the variable is `lastName`. Maybe you could encourage something like that instead?

Comment: It's something I am trying to do. Only difference, I think, between our views it's the emphasis - when you say "encourage", i have to say "encourage by providing coding style guideline".

Comment: @ts: See http://www.turbulentintellect.com/2011/03/strategy-vs-tactics-in-coding-standards.html

Answer (score 0):

Many people usually prefer to adopt the conventions already adopted in the language they use.
E.g. in java it would be **databaseName** and in C++ **database_name**